# Separating Button Click Behavior

Tags: angularjs

Running through an example from the book, [AngularJS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449344852), why does clicking the `Reset` button result in the alert, `sorry, please get more customers.`?

I only want the `alert` to occur when pressing the `Fund my startup!` button.

```
<html ng-app>
<body>

    <script src=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js">
      </script>

    <form ng-submit="requestFunding()" ng-controller="StartUpController">
        Starting: <input ng-change="computeNeeded()" ng-model="startingEstimate">
        Recommendation: {{needed}}
        <button>Fund my startup!</button>
        <button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        function StartUpController($scope) {
            $scope.computeNeeded = function() {
                $scope.needed= $scope.startingEstimate * 10;
            };

            $scope.requestFunding = function() { 
                window.alert("sorry, please get more customers.");
            };

            $scope.reset = function() {
                $scope.startingEstimate = 0;
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default button on-click behavior (which is submit)

## The most explicit way in angular:

Following is a one way.  (You could create a directive for this purpose, too.)

template:

```
    <button ng-click="reset($event)">Reset</button>
```

javascript:

```
    $scope.reset = function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $scope.startingEstimate = 0;
    };
```

## somewhat implicit way in general html:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
```

This works by overriding the type attribute of button element 
which happens to be 'submit'.

Comment: Why is the default behavior of a button `submit` to call `reset()`?

Comment: The other way around: Reset button is firing the submit because the default behavior of any button is to submit.

Comment: As a result, all button presses (in scope of controller?), i.e. `submit`'s, will result in `reset()` getting called, unless we use your `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: "Plain buttons fire Submit".  So reset button will fire submit as default and I tried to show ways to prevent that.  BTW, it has nothing to do with the framework (in this example, AngularJS).